# wpf faulty class diagram, inheritance for userControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

So, after some searching on stackoverflow and on google, I did find a few answers on my question but didn't know how to actually implement it for my own use. Which is why I will ask it again here.

Because of my inexperience with wpf combined with that I have never used anything closely resembling it, I made the mistake of going into creating a class diagram which now(maybe) has to be completely changed.

I wasn't sure of how I would go about creating custom blocks, but kind of mapped out the behaviour I needed.

[close example of what I was trying to work towards](https://pxt.microbit.org/?lang=nl)

After realizing I made a mistake after finding out about userControls I tried implementing this into my project.

This is a test I made:

*base class*

```
namespace TestTest
{
  public abstract partial class TestBase : UserControl
   {
      public TestBase()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
      public virtual void doSomething()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("ITS WORKING");
      }
   }
}
```

*Child class*

```
namespace TestTest
{
  public partial class TestExtend : TestBase
   {
      public TestExtend()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

after this I tried to add testExtended to a canvas but it gave the type error: testExtended is not a UIElement

[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBLvB.png) (both UIStackBlock and UISideBlock inherit from UIBlock and UIBlock is free to inherit from anything)

I will still need the inheritance I created for filtering out certain blocks(mostly on UIOperations)

Now my real question is, how would I go about adding multiple xaml files and defining the look of them in there without getting in the way of the current inheritance hierarchy I have in place. Or is this even achievable?

Again, I know this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write DataTemplates that are adjusted per DataType.
Or, you could leave behind inheriting from UserControl(just Inherit from Control or ContentControl) and make each of them a custom control with its unique style and Template.

Comment: I have to add the blocks dynamically in code, could you give me an example of how I would go about predefining the style and template of the blocks before instantiation or point me to applicable and understandable documentation?

Comment: Its ok its meant to work that way. you create an instance. the framework will provide the default style per control type:

https://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: One more question, how do I go about adding multiple multiple controls into one, since that was the biggest reason I was going to use a usercontrol.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question..
When you write the ControlTemplate for your control, you can insert as much controls as you want there.

Comment: ha, I am sorry I made a mistake which caused the problem  I was having. Thanks for the help!